# Widget icon created twice

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, widget, android-widget

I'm new to android app development. I came across weird problem. I search google but I am unable to get answer. I request, if somebody knows answer please post.

I develop an app with widget. I specified the app install location as auto which makes the app can be moved to SD card.After install the app, I created widget in the home screen.

Since app install location is auto, I moved the app to SD card, after widget is added to home screen. When I move back the app to phone, android is having two widget icon. I can't understand why two widget icon is created in widget container.

Can anybody help me please???